# JavaScript and Struts Localization

Tags: javascript, struts

I am using struts localization for formatting number in the following manner using the getText method.

Is there someway i could utilize this same method using jquery. i want to format the number using this method in javascript as well.

Can anyone tell me how i can do this?

Regards,
Kaddy

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your JavaScript is located you have a number of options:

If it's in the JSP file, use JSTL/JSP EL/Struts tags as usual.

If it's in a JS file, either:

1. Pass the formatted number as an argument to the JS function (or expose as a global).
2. Put the formatted number in a hidden DOM element and retrieve it using jQuery.
3. Pass your JS file through the JSP processor (works, but can get messy).